# Converting Either[L, R] to a value of a common supertype of L and R

Tags: scala

If I have a value of type `Either[A, B]`, where `A extends T` and `B extends T`, how can I most easily get a value of type `T`? Anything more elegant than pattern matching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `merge`:

```
val e: Either[A, B] = ???
val result: T = e.merge
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fold` with the identity function on both sides - will the one that exists:

```
val e: Either[A, B] = ???
val result: T = e.fold(identity[T], identity[T])
```

Comment: Although...just found `merge`, which does the trick even better ;-)

Comment: I think your own answer is better, maybe you should accept it instead.